# Visual Studio C++ application not to require MSVCP110.dll library

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, dll, static-linking

I have just finished my C++ application written in Visual Studio 2012. I'm having no problems with it, however my client running his PC on Windows 7 is having the following issue while launching:

[image]

I guess he could simply install [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) however, I would rather not want to force them to do so. So the question is, is this possible to launch my application without installing additional Windows addons or delivering the library along with my `.exe` file? I assume I would have to use static linking, and here is another problem since I'm using Qt and don't want (or can't) statically link Qt libraries. Is there any solution to skip static linking for certain libraries in visual studio?

Comment: So you don't want users of your program to install one dependency (the MSVC runtime), but it's okay to install another dependency (the Qt framework)? That doesn't makes much sense to me.

Comment: Basic rule is all static or all dynamic.  There are corner cases when you can mix and match but only if you understand all the issues.

Comment: You have to install the redistributable for the comiler version you compiled  your program on in windows. There is no way around it. You can build an installer which automatically installs it but this has to be installed. For distributing those an installer would probably the best solution

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Who said I have to install Qt framework dependency? I never said that, those are linked dynamically and I'm okay with that.

Comment: @Hayt An installer that is downloading & installing redistributable for Visual Studio 2012? I don't understand

Comment: So how will the users of your program get the Qt DLL files? Will you ship it with your program? Will they be installed by your installer? Will the users have to install it themselves? If you ship with the Qt DLL files, or put them in the installer, why can't you do the same with the MSVC runtime DLL files?

Comment: `Will you ship it with your program?` Yes. `why can't you do the same with the MSVC runtime DLL files` because I thought these files could be installed only with `Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012`? Would it still work if I'd just copy a DLL from my system and deliver it with my exe? AFAIK redistributable package could be still updated eg. for security reasons. Btw. if I would use an installer, I could simply put these files in the `Windows/system32` instead of delivering it with my exe at the same folder?

Comment: Your program *also* has a dependency on msvcr110.dll.  Having that DLL present but not msvcp110.dll is a wonky machine problem.  Nothing you can do about a wonky machine but get it fixed, run the redist installer.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm pretty sure there is a way to not force users to install redist. I would rather suicide than have to reply each email regarding this issue since it's pretty common. Turns out it's Windows fault not being ready to execute C++ written applications without static linking.

Comment: Sure, it is also Windows' fault that it does not include the QT dlls.  Categorically refusing to copy two more dlls is however entirely your problem.  Maybe you should just leave it up to the end-user to fix your problem, they tend to be a lot more pragmatic about it.

Comment: @HansPassant Please read the question and comments I wrote once again and stop linking the issue to the Qt dlls because that is not my actual problem.

Comment: @HansPassant (couldn't edit) I deliver my app with Qt dlls but what do you think, I should deliver it with the redist installer as well and prompt the user to not forget to install redist, because Microsoft forgot to care about that?

Comment: You are entirely too hung-up on the redist installer.  Do not use it at all, it is meant for end-users.  All you have to do is copy two more DLLs into the install directory of your app, msvcr110.dll and msvcp110.dll.   Use the ones in your c:\windows\syswow64 directory, assuming that you compiled your QT app to target x86.

Comment: Alright, I wasn't sure if I'm allowed to do that, especially for the compatibility reasons.